# Как исправить проблему с url картинки на GitHub Pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, github-pages

Есть проблема с **url** картинок. Для маршрутизации сайта я использую **react-router-dom**. При переходе на страну название репозитории **cat-foot-landing** заменяется на название в ссылки, по-этому и картинки нету.

Корректный путь к картинке: https://alexanderokhotnichenko.github.io/cat-foot-landing/img/catallog/catalog_1_500.webp

Путь который получаю я: https://alexanderokhotnichenko.github.io/img/catallog/catalog_1_500.webp

репозиторий [GitHub](https://github.com/AlexanderOkhotnichenko/cat-foot-landing)

Я пробовал изменить путь, но все эти варианты не помогли мне.

```
<Link to="/catallog">каталог продукции</Link>
<Link to="./catallog">каталог продукции</Link>
<Link to="../catallog">каталог продукции</Link>
<Link to="./cat-foot-landing/catallog">каталог продукции</Link>
```

Роутер

```
<Routes>
   <Route exact path="/" element={<PageHome />}></Route>
   <Route path="/catallog" element={<PageCatallog />}></Route>
   <Route path="/form" element={<PageForm />}></Route>
</Routes>
```

---

```
<nav className={`${styles.content__menu} ${styles.menu} ${isToggle ? styles.open : ''}`}>
   <ul className={ styles.menu__list }>
      <li className={ styles.menu__item }><Link onClick={onCloseMenu} to="./">главная</Link></li>
      <li className={ styles.menu__item }><Link onClick={onCloseMenu} to="./catallog">каталог продукции</Link></li>
      <li className={ styles.menu__item }><Link onClick={onCloseMenu} to="./form">подбор программы</Link></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: А где элемент с картинкой, про которую вопрос? Может вам стоит указать полный путь до картинки?

Comment: @SwaD Путь относительный из папки public/img/catallog/catalog_1_1000.webp

Comment: Попробуйте использовать полный путь. Либо хардкодом вставить, либо собрать с помощью `window.location`